# Merging Ranges In C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, merge, range

I have a list of randomly ordered unique closed-end ranges R<sub>0</sub>...R<sub>n-1</sub> where

> R<sub>i</sub> = [r1<sub>i</sub>, r2<sub>i</sub>] (r1<sub>i</sub> <= r2<sub>i</sub>)

Subsequently some of the ranges overlap (partially or completely) and hence require merging.

My question is, what are the best-of-breed algorithms or techniques used for merging such ranges. Examples of such algorithms or links to libraries that perform such a merging operation would be great.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

What you need to do is:

1. Sort items lexicographically where range key is [r_start,r_end]
2. Iterate the sorted list and check if current item overlaps with next. If it does extend current item to be r[i].start,r[i+1].end, and goto next item. If it doesn't overlap add current to result list and move to next item.

Here is sample code:

```
    vector<pair<int, int> > ranges;
    vector<pair<int, int> > result;
    sort(ranges.begin(),ranges.end());
    vector<pair<int, int> >::iterator it = ranges.begin();
    pair<int,int> current = *(it)++;
    while (it != ranges.end()){
       if (current.second > it->first){ // you might want to change it to >=
           current.second = std::max(current.second, it->second); 
       } else {
           result.push_back(current);
           current = *(it);
       }
       it++;
    }
    result.push_back(current);
```

Comment: Would the overall complexity of this approach be O(nlogn) {Essentially sort-complexity + 1 linear scan of N} ?

Comment: Depending on the size of the space the values fit in, it may be much more efficient to use a radix sort rather than quick sort. Radix sort is O(kn) where k is the size of the key space.

Comment: How does your algorithm handle cases, when the `r[i].end + 1 == r[i+1].start`? - Actually, this ranges can be merged too.

Answer (score 12):

[**Boost.Icl**](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/icl/doc/html/index.html) might be of use for you.

The library offers a few templates that you may use in your situation:

- interval_set — Implements a set as a set of intervals -  merging adjoining intervals.
- separate_interval_set — Implements a set as a set of intervals - leaving adjoining intervals separate
- split_interval_set — implements a set as a set of intervals - on insertion overlapping intervals are split

There is an [**example**](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/icl/doc/html/boost_icl/examples/interval_container.html) for merging intervals with the library  :

```
interval<Time>::type night_and_day(Time(monday,   20,00), Time(tuesday,  20,00));
interval<Time>::type day_and_night(Time(tuesday,   7,00), Time(wednesday, 7,00));
interval<Time>::type  next_morning(Time(wednesday, 7,00), Time(wednesday,10,00));
interval<Time>::type  next_evening(Time(wednesday,18,00), Time(wednesday,21,00));

// An interval set of type interval_set joins intervals that that overlap or touch each other.
interval_set<Time> joinedTimes;
joinedTimes.insert(night_and_day);
joinedTimes.insert(day_and_night); //overlapping in 'day' [07:00, 20.00)
joinedTimes.insert(next_morning);  //touching
joinedTimes.insert(next_evening);  //disjoint

cout << "Joined times  :" << joinedTimes << endl;
```

and the output of this algorithm:

```
Joined times  :[mon:20:00,wed:10:00)[wed:18:00,wed:21:00)
```

And here about complexity of their algorithms:

[Time Complexity of Addition](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/icl/doc/html/boost_icl/implementation/complexity.html)

Answer (score 3):

A simple algorithm would be:

- Sort the ranges by starting values
- Iterate over the ranges from beginning to end, and whenever you find a range that overlaps with the next one, merge them

Comment: Instead of sorting, could a std::priority_queue be used = sort of like sweep-line approach?

Comment: Since you just want to walk over them from lowest to biggest a `std::priority_queue` should work, but I don't think it would be faster/... than just sorting. After all you walk over all items in order, so you end up with them being sorted.

Comment: @Rikardo a priority queue is only helpful when items arrive over time. If you have all of them, just sort them. Best-of-breed priority queue and sort are both O(nlogn) (priority queue is n insertions with O(logn) per insertion), but sort performs better and has less overhead.

Comment: @JimBalter Could you please see my answer below and let me know your opinion?

Answer (score 3):

O(n*log(n)+2n):

- Make a mapping of `r1_i -> r2_i`,
- QuickSort upon the `r1_i`'s,
- go through the list to select for each `r1_i`-value the largest `r2_i`-value,
- with that `r2_i`-value you can skip over all *subsequent* `r1_i`'s that are smaller than `r2_i`

Comment: Just a little point: O(n*log(n) + 2n) = O(n*log(n) + n) = O(n*log(n))

Comment: of course. but (altho not in theory) such differences are significant in practice

Comment: It's meaningless to say there's a difference in practice, because big-O is a theoretically defined notion and by its definition, O(nlogn+2n) = O(nlogn).

Comment: Consider that quicksort is O(nlogn) but that could mean that its O(nlogn+40n) making your algorithm actually O(nlogn+42n) ... = O(nlogn).

Comment: @Jim Balter: I agreed with `andand` that there is no difference in theory! And no it's not meaningless to say "there's a difference in practice". In practice practice is everything and big-oh's that make no difference in theory can totally ruin you!

Comment: I recently implemented this method for a program which merges lists of IPv4 address ranges. Of all the methods I've implemented and tested this was by far the most efficient. I wrote an example to illustrate the method: [RangeMap at play.golang.org](http://play.golang.org/p/WpOsxC3EEH)

Comment: @BeMasher great to hear! i took a look but i haven't learnt Go yet, so i can't say anything about it.

Answer (score 2):

jethro's answer contains an error.
It should be

```
if (current.second > it->first){
    current.second = std::max(current.second, it->second);        
} else {
```

Comment: This should have been an edit to jethro's answer rather than its own answer.

Answer (score 1):

My algorithm does not use extra space and is lightweight as well. I have used `2-pointer` approach. 'i' keeps increasing while 'j' keeps track of the current element being updated.
Here is my code:

```
bool cmp(Interval a,Interval b)
 {
     return a.start<=b.start;
 }
vector<Interval> Solution::insert(vector<Interval> &intervals, Interval newInterval) {
    int i,j;
    sort(intervals.begin(),intervals.end(),cmp);
    i=1,j=0;
    while(i<intervals.size())
    {
        if(intervals[j].end>=intervals[i].start)  //if overlaps
        {
            intervals[j].end=max(intervals[i].end,intervals[j].end); //change
        }
        else
        {
            j++;
            intervals[j]=intervals[i];  //update it on the same list
        }
        i++;
    }
    intervals.erase(intervals.begin()+j+1,intervals.end());
    return intervals;
}
```

Interval can be a public class or structure with data members 'start' and 'end'.
Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is a long time after the original accepted answer. But in
c++11, we can now construct a priority_queue in the following manner`

```
priority_queue( const Compare& compare, const Container& cont )
```

in O(n) comparisons.

Please see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/priority_queue
for more details.

So we can create a priority_queue(min heap) of pairs in O(n) time. Get the lowest interval in O(1) and pop it in O(log(n)) time. 
So the overall time complexity is close to O(nlog(n) + 2n) = O(nlogn)