# Merge 2 arrays containing data range in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, range

Is it possible to merge 2 arrays by its data range in jQuery?
The length of arrays can be different.

Array 1:

```
[{"start":0,"end":15},{"start":20,"end":25},{"start":50,"end":120}]
```

Array 2:

```
[{"start":0,"end":5},{"start":10,"end":22},{"start":45,"end":100}]
```

The final array should look like this:

```
[{"start":0,"end":25},{"start":45,"end":120}]
```

Please help.
Thx.

Comment: It's certainly possible but you need to show an attempt at solving this yourself, and also explain the logic behind merging better. For example, why does `end` become `200` in the merged sample?

Comment: RoryMcCrossan it was a typo. I've edited.

Comment: Not at all clear what the relationship is here between input and output

Comment: Looks like the output is the summed ranges from the input arrays (the output's start and end ranges cover everything that is within any start/end range in any input, ignoring overlap.)   @AdrianChicu are "start" and "end" always integer values?

Comment: @DanielBeck Yes, only integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5276686/merging-ranges-in-c) has been asked in C++, I have ported [this pseudo code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5276786/1068131) algorithm to Javascript:

> - Sort the ranges by starting values
> - Iterate over the ranges from beginning to end, and whenever you find a range that overlaps with the next one, merge them

```js
function merge(...inputs) {
    input = [].concat(...inputs);
    input.sort((a, b) => a.start > b.start);    
    let output = [];
    for (let i=0; i<input.length; i++) {
        if (input[i+1] && input[i].end >= input[i+1].start) {
            // The current range overlaps with the next one: merge them
            input[i].end = Math.max(input[i].end, input[i+1].end);
            // Remove the range we just merged into the current one
            input.splice(i+1, 1);
            // And move back the iterator by one position to keep
            // it pointing to the current range at the next iteration
            i--;
        } else {
            // The current range doesn't overlap with the next one,
            // just copy that to the result
            output.push(input[i]);
        }
    }
    return output;
}

let input1 = [{"start":0,"end":15},{"start":20,"end":25},{"start":50,"end":120}];
let input2 = [{"start":0,"end":5},{"start":10,"end":22},{"start":45,"end":100}];

console.log(merge(input1, input2));
```

Comment: Nice! This is much better than my approach.

Comment: One nitpick: `if (input[i+1] && input[i].end > input[i+1].start)` should be `>=`, in case ranges end and start at the same number

Answer (score 1):

Here's a rather brute-force solution. This will only work with non-negative integer values (because I'm depending on array index to keep track of the 'start' and 'end' values) but it will accept any number of input arrays, of any length, in any order. Comments within the snippet explain how it works:

```js
// The ... operator is the only ES6 syntax I'm using here; 
// it's so the fn can accept any number of input arrays.  If 
// you don't care about that and aren't transpiling from ES6 
// just concat the two inputs instead to create `inputranges`:
var doMerge = function(...inputs) {

  // we don't care which input came from which array, 
  // so just merge them all:
  var inputranges = [].concat(...inputs);

  // This will eventually contain 1 for every index that's within 
  // a start/end range:
  var isWithinRange = [];

  // fill 'isWithinRange': 
  for (var range of inputranges) {
    for (var i = range.start; i <= range.end; i++) {
      isWithinRange[i] = 1
    }
  };
  isWithinRange.push(undefined); // so we'll catch the end of the last range later on

  // Now we need to convert isWithinRange back into start/end pairs. 
  // I'm sure there's a more elegant way to do this, but I'm just going
  // to step through the whole list and find places where it 
  // transitions from undefined to 1 or vice-versa:
  var output = [];
  var lastStartSeen = -1; // keeps track of the "start" of the current range while we iterate

  for (i = 0; i < isWithinRange.length; i++) {
    if (isWithinRange[i] && lastStartSeen === -1) {
      // this is the beginning of a new range; capture i for later
      lastStartSeen = i;
    }
    if (!isWithinRange[i] && lastStartSeen !== -1) {
      // we've just exited a range; put it in the output:
      output.push({
        "start": lastStartSeen,
        "end": i - 1
      });
      lastStartSeen = -1;
    }
  }
  return output;
}

var input1 = [
  {"start": 0, "end": 15},
  {"start": 20, "end": 25},
  {"start": 50, "end": 120}
];

var input2 = [
  {"start": 0, "end": 5},
  {"start": 10, "end": 22},
  {"start": 45, "end": 100}
];

var out = doMerge(input1, input2);
console.log(out);
```

Comment: This perfectly covered my requirements.
Thx Daniel.