# Is there an algorithm for checking that a series of ranges form one continuous range?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, range

I'm looking for an algorithm to check if an inputted selection of random float ranges forms one continuous range, and return either the full continuous range or the ranges it covers.

For example, say someone inputs the following:

```
[16.0f, 40.0f], [30.0f, 55.0f], [1.0f, 25.0f]
```

I need the algorithm to say that it is continuous and returns `[1.0f, 55.0f]`.

However, if someone inputs:

```
[10.0f, 25.0f], [5.0f, 9.0f], [1.0f, 7.0f], [20.0f, 34.0f]
```

I need the algorithm to say it is not a continuous range and returns `[1.0f, 9.0f], [10.0f, 34.0f]`.

What I currently do is something along the lines of:

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < InIntervalRanges.num(); ++i)
{
    const Interval CurrentRange = InIntervalRanges[i];

    bool bAddedToRange = false;
    for (Interval& AllowedHeight : OutIntervalRanges)
    {
        if (AllowedHeight.Contains(CurrentRange.Min))
        {
            AllowedHeight.Include(CurrentRange.Max);
            bAddedToRange = true;
            break;
        }
        if (AllowedHeight.Contains(CurrentRange.Max))
        {
            AllowedHeight.Include(CurrentRange.Min);
            bAddedToRange = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!bAddedToRange)
    {
        OutIntervalRanges.Add(CurrentRange);
    }
}

if (OutIntervalRanges.Num() > 1)
{
    return false;
}

return true;
```

Where `Interval` has a `Min` and `Max`, `Contains` checks if a value is within the range of the Interval, and `Include` expands the Interval range to include a value if it isn't already in the range.

Is there a more efficient algorithm for this? I'm not expecting large numbers of intervals but I wonder if there is a more efficient way to do this?

EDIT: Added an attempted solution for it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this looks to me like a school assignment which should be done by the OP and not by the StackOverflow community.

Comment: This question would be more appropriate for SO if you add an attempted solution with explanation of why your solution doesn't work/where the issue arises.

Comment: Your question does not make any sense to me. It looks like you just need the min and the max. But in your second example you split up between two maxes and minimums, what is the logic exactly?

Comment: Sort the ranges in ascending order of their left border and merge ranges greedily. This question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/5276686/14410812

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you still have your problem, but I came across this same problem when creating an agenda for availability.

I decided to create a "continuum" class that represents the complete number- or timeline. (limited to a subset)

This is what I ended up with:

```cs
namespace Continuum;

using System.Collections;

/// <summary>
/// Collection class representing a continuum with enabled and disabled ranges.
/// </summary>
public class Continuum<TItem> : IReadOnlyList<(TItem Start, TItem End)>
    where TItem : IComparable, IComparable<TItem>, IEquatable<TItem>
{
    private readonly List<(TItem Start, TItem End)> intervals = new();

    public Continuum(TItem minValue, TItem maxValue)
    {
        MinValue = minValue;
        MaxValue = maxValue;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The lower bound of the continuum.
    /// Ranges are clipped to this value.
    /// </summary>
    public TItem MinValue { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The upper bound of the continuum.
    /// Ranges are clipped to this value.
    /// </summary>
    public TItem MaxValue { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Modifies a range in the continuum.
    /// </summary>
    public void Modify(TItem start, TItem end, bool enabled)
    {
        if (enabled) Add(start, end);
        else Remove(start, end);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds a range to the continuum. 
    /// If the range overlaps with existing ranges, they are merged.
    /// If the range is out of bound, it is clipped or ignored.
    /// </summary>
    public void Add(TItem start, TItem end)
    {
        if (!TryFixRange(ref start, ref end)) return;
        (var index, var overlapCount) = FindIndex(start, end);
        if (overlapCount > 0)
        {
            if (intervals[index].Start.CompareTo(start) < 0) start = intervals[index].Start;
            if (intervals[index + overlapCount - 1].End.CompareTo(end) > 0) end = intervals[index].End;
            intervals.RemoveRange(index, overlapCount);
        }
        intervals.Insert(index, (start, end));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Removes a range from the continuum. 
    /// Existing ranges are partially or completely removed.
    /// If the range is out of bound, it is clipped or ignored.
    /// </summary>
    public void Remove(TItem start, TItem end)
    {
        if (!TryFixRange(ref start, ref end)) return;
        (var index, var overlapCount) = FindIndex(start, end);
        if (overlapCount == 0) return;
        var startOfFirstIntervalToClip = intervals[index].Start;
        var endOfLastIntervalToClip = intervals[index + overlapCount - 1].End;
        intervals.RemoveRange(index, overlapCount);
        if (endOfLastIntervalToClip.CompareTo(end) > 0) intervals.Insert(index, (end, endOfLastIntervalToClip));
        if (startOfFirstIntervalToClip.CompareTo(start) < 0) intervals.Insert(index, (startOfFirstIntervalToClip, start));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Tries to fix a range by clipping it to the bounds of the continuum.
    /// </summary>
    private bool TryFixRange(ref TItem start, ref TItem end)
    {
        if (start.CompareTo(end) >= 0 || start.CompareTo(MaxValue) >= 0 || end.CompareTo(MinValue) <= 0) return false;
        if (MinValue.CompareTo(start) > 0) start = MinValue;
        if (MaxValue.CompareTo(end) < 0) end = MaxValue;
        return true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Find the index where to insert or delete the range, 
    /// plus the number of existing adjacent ranges that overlap with the range.
    /// </summary>
    private (int index, int overlapCount) FindIndex(TItem start, TItem end)
    {
        var i = 0;
        while (i < intervals.Count && intervals[i].End.CompareTo(start) < 0) i++;
        var c = 0;
        while (i + c < intervals.Count && intervals[i + c].Start.CompareTo(end) <= 0) c++;
        return (i, c);
    }

    /// <inheritdoc/>
    public int Count => intervals.Count;
    /// <inheritdoc/>
    public (TItem Start, TItem End) this[int index] => intervals[index];
    /// <inheritdoc/>
    public IEnumerator<(TItem Start, TItem End)> GetEnumerator() => intervals.GetEnumerator();
    /// <inheritdoc/>
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();

    /// <summary>
    /// Determines the enabled state at a given point in the continuum.
    /// </summary>
    public bool this[TItem key] => intervals.Exists(i => i.Start.CompareTo(key) <= 0 && i.End.CompareTo(key) > 0);

    /// <summary>
    /// Clips the continuum to the given range.
    /// </summary>
    public void Clip(TItem start, TItem end)
    {
        Remove(MinValue, start);
        Remove(end, MaxValue);
    }
}
```

It can be called, e.g. with dates, like this:

```cs
var schedule = new Continuum<DateTime>(new DateTime(2000, 6, 1), new DateTime(2000, 6, 8));

schedule.Add(new DateTime(2000, 6, 1, 12, 0, 0), new DateTime(2000, 6, 1, 15, 0, 0));
schedule.Add(new DateTime(2000, 6, 1, 11, 0, 0), new DateTime(2000, 6, 1, 13, 0, 0));
schedule.Add(new DateTime(2000, 6, 1, 14, 0, 0), new DateTime(2000, 6, 1, 16, 0, 0));

schedule.Add(new DateTime(2000, 6, 2, 12, 0, 0), new DateTime(2000, 6, 2, 15, 0, 0));
schedule.Add(new DateTime(2000, 6, 2, 11, 0, 0), new DateTime(2000, 6, 2, 12, 0, 0));
schedule.Add(new DateTime(2000, 6, 2, 15, 0, 0), new DateTime(2000, 6, 2, 16, 0, 0));

schedule.Add(new DateTime(2000, 6, 3, 10, 0, 0), new DateTime(2000, 6, 3, 17, 0, 0));
schedule.Remove(new DateTime(2000,6,3, 9, 0,0), new DateTime(2000,6,3, 11, 0,0));
schedule.Remove(new DateTime(2000, 6, 3, 16, 0, 0), new DateTime(2000, 6, 3, 18, 0, 0));

foreach (var s in schedule)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{s.Start} - {s.End}");
}

<!-- end snippet -->
```